# How do i draw a REAL dotted line in android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, draw

I am trying to draw a dotted line as a separator for a `ListView` divider item, as shown here:
[image]

In order to do that, in one of the cases I have overridden the `OnDraw()` method and used:

`paint.SetPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new[] { 2f, 2f }, 0));`

`_paint.StrokeWidth = 2;`

Using `DashPathEffect` dows draw small dots - but they are not dots - they are small squares rather than rounded dots:

[image]

The app is built using monodroid on Xamarin's framework

Any thoughts?

Comment: try adding `paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);` and `paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);` as well...

Comment: @M-WaJeEh when assigning this: `_paint.SetPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new[] { 2f, 2f }, 0)); _paint.StrokeWidth = 2; _paint.StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round;` I get a full solid line.. any other configuration suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

setting paint

```
 mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 mPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);
 mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{1, 60}, 0f));
 mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
```

example of use

```
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

**UPDATE**

There is another way. Here you can set absolutely any shape

```
    paintBlue = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    float mRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    paintBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintBlue.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintBlue.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paintBlue.setStrokeWidth(12);
    Path shapePath = new Path();
    shapePath.addCircle(0, 0, mRadius, Path.Direction.CCW);
    PathDashPathEffect pathDashPathEffect = new PathDashPathEffect(shapePath, mRadius * 4, 0, PathDashPathEffect.Style.ROTATE);
    paintBlue.setPathEffect(pathDashPathEffect);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing on device with API level>=11 then try [setting layer type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to [LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)

Comment: Just wrap setting layer type with if like this: ```if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>x)```

Comment: On API level<11 layer type is always software, so nothing should be done in such cases. Optionally you can add ```@TargetApi``` lint annotation.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, im running on Xamarin's platdorm our current target framework is 10, as explained here [link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12400) the target framework will have to be set to 11+ in order to even use `setLayerType`.. any other suggestions

Comment: You can set target to 11 or higher and ```minSdkVersion``` to 9. Then application will run on API>=9.